# for loop .. wait for AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am iterating through a series of dates with the code below. each time, I make an ajax request and return xml data which then calls a function to display a series of divs on a row on my page.  The problem is my loop has completed before even the first ajax call, How can I hold the for loop until my ajax request and function has completed ? Any help much appreciated ! , thanks

```
        // Start of the loop for the date range selected    

        for(loopTime = startTime; loopTime <= endTime; loopTime += 86400000)   {

        // Produce the day from the date 
                loopDate=new Date(loopTime) 
                day = loopDate.getDate() ;          if (day < 10) { day = "0" + day } ; 
                mon = loopDate.getMonth()+1   ; if (mon < 10) { mon = "0" + mon } ; 
                year = loopDate.getFullYear()       
                epDate = year + "-" + mon + "-" + day 

        // Run the XML Query ONCE ONLY 
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "php_assoc/jobs_today.php",
                  data: { OnThisDate : epDate },
                  dataType: "xml",
                  success:returnedXMLdata             
                  });

        }// for loop date




        function returnedXMLdata(data) {
            script ....
```

Comment: The A in AJAX stands for asynchonous, meaning a call is executed and goes off on its own and answers in the "callback" portion of the code ("success"). Be clear what you need here.

Comment: what particular problem is this causing?  Overload of the server because the AJAX calls all happen at once?

Comment: The callback creates a row of divs starting with the date (epDate) , The problems is that I get row after row of the same date, which happens to be the last date in my for loop /, What I want to achieve is similar to a calendar with a list of dates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is presumably not that the loop finishes early (that's actually a good thing) but that all of the AJAX requests get fired almost immediately.

If you wish to enqueue your AJAX requests, you need to make the loop iterate using the event handlers themselves, and without using `for`:

```
var loopTime = startTime;
(function iterate() {
    $.ajax(...).always(function() {
        loopTime += 86400 * 1000;
        if (loopTime <= endTime) {
            iterate();
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thank you. Save me a day

Answer (score 3):

Inside the ajax request, add an async property and set it to false.

```
async: false,
```

Comment: Whilst this will fix the problem, it is *very*, ***very*** bad practise to use synchronous AJAX requests; your browser will be locked up and unusable for the duration of *all* your AJAX requests.

Comment: @Matt +1, never, ever, ever, ever make _synchronous_ AJAX calls.  It's such a bad idea that they're actually going to remove it in a future version of jQuery

Comment: This is a bad recommendation.  sync ajax calls lock up the browser.  This is never a better user experience than a proper async design.